# How to create XHR request in angular2?

Tags: http, angular, xmlhttprequest, image-uploading, observable

I created Image uploader using angular2 http post request. Now I want to track the progress of the Image which is being uploaded which is possible using xmlHTTP request but I can not find the proper format for that.

here is my code for http image uploader.

```
    uploadImage(eventId:number,formData:any): Observable<any[]> {
    // update location info of an event
    let headers = new Headers({ **Some necessary headers** });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/events/uploads',formData, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Which works as expected. Now how can I track progress of my Image being uploaded?